# Strange behaviour of custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

I got a question to a ListView, which I want to customize. The ListView should provide the functionality of a RingtonePreference. For the most part this is working very well, but the way the ListView is shown to the user is not consistent. I tried different approaches but my custom ListView is split in two sections or the Buttons of the Dialog are out of the range. See picture down below..

Here is my code:

```
   @Override
        protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        String mThemeSettings = MyVars.THEME_KEY_DEFAULT;

        // Theme-Einstellungen
        if (preferences.contains(MyVars.SETTING_THEME)) {
            mThemeSettings = preferences.getString(MyVars.SETTING_THEME, yVars.THEME_KEY_DEFAULT);
        } else {
            editor.putString(MyVars.SETTING_THEME, mThemeSettings);
            editor.apply();
        }

        // View für Rückgabe anlegen
        View view;

        if (mThemeSettings.equals(MyVars.THEME_KEY_2)) {
            view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.custom_list_preference_black, null);
        } else view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.custom_list_preference_white, null);

        mDialogTitle = getDialogTitle();
        if (mDialogTitle == null) mDialogTitle = getTitle();
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title)).setText(mDialogTitle);

        ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
        if (mThemeSettings.equals(MyVars.THEME_KEY_2)) {

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
                    getContext(), R.layout.btn_radio_black,
                    getEntries());
        } else {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
                    getContext(), R.layout.btn_radio_white,
                    getEntries());
        }

        // Adapter setzen
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Achtung: vorher Clickable setzen, sonst werden die Vorgaben nicht angenommen...
        list.setClickable(true);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        list.setItemChecked(findIndexOfValue(mPath), true);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(@NonNull Builder builder) {
        super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);

        // Holo-Titel unsichtbar machen
        builder.setTitle(null);

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mEntries = getEntries();
        mEntryValues = getEntryValues();

        builder.setPositiveButton(mContext.getString(R.string.btn_ok), this);
        builder.setNegativeButton(mContext.getString(R.string.btn_cancel), this);

    }
```

and the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:background="@color/blue_app_color"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:listSelector="@color/blue_app_color"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect when you have a fixed heigh ListView?

Either use weight or make your ListView take up the remainder of the screen with:

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    .../>
```

Comment: Ahh, I just copied the wrong code :-/ The buttons get out of screen when I match parent the ListView...